# is there a way to know if deflate (or your Z_STREAM) has data being buffered? zlib C++

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

does zlib let you know if you have data being buffered waiting for deflate until there is a decent amount of data to compress? would one of the variables in Z_STREAM, or elsewhere be able to show this?

Basically I want to force the z stream to flush, but only on end of file (on a file that is constantly updated) so read, compress til eof, read,  compress til eof etc. If I make flush z_finish on eof and then call resetdeflate before next read that should do the trick right? It should flush the buffer, reset the stream and continue on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, deflate does not have a variable or a function that will tell you how much data has been accumulated, before it emits compressed data. There is a different question it can answer, with `deflatePending()`, which will tell you how many compressed bytes and bits of an emitted block are yet to be written to the user's output buffer.

Yes, to end a deflate stream you use Z_FINISH and then call `deflate()` until it has no more output for you. You can follow that with a `deflateReset()` to reuse the structure to start a new deflate stream.

If you do this frequently, e.g. for every line written to a file, then you will get lousy compression since a single line will generally not be very compressible. What you may be looking for is something like [`gzlog`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h), which adds lines to a compressed gzip file, maintaining its correctness as a compress gzip stream on each append, while still providing good compression.